# Is it faster to travel as a werewolf than riding a horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a horse actually faster than running?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/is-a-horse-actually-faster-than-running)

Is it faster to travel as a werewolf than riding a horse? And which one is faster at climbing, werewolves or horses? Not including time it takes to feed on travelers.

Comment: The answer you seek be here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/is-a-horse-actually-faster-than-running#answer-36521

Comment: Okay, I didn't expect the answer to be in that question. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

It is.

As you can see, I actually answered to this question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/is-a-horse-actually-faster-than-running/36521#36521). Unfortunately, I don't have Skyrim anymore to backup my claims with screenshots.

Long story short, running as werewolf is around 20% faster than with horse. Also, while in werewolf form, you gain 100 more stamina (which is used to fuel your sprint). If you are playing rouge or warrior you should already have high stamina. In other words, werewolf's sprint can scale to some degree with your character progression. Also, if I recall correctly, the werewolf regenerates stamina much faster than a horse.

Downside is, you can only be 2.5 min in this form and you can only open your map while you're a werewolf by going to the pause menu and selecting the "view quest" option on one of your active quest.
If you decide this form to be your primary way of transportation, I highly recommending obtaining [Hiricine's Ring](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hircine%27s_Ring_%28Skyrim%29), which gives you unlimited transformations (in werewolf form) per day.