# What are the benefits of having a horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently acquired [Frost](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Frost_(Horse)) after:

> Successfully persuading Louis Letrush at the end of [Promises to Keep](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Promises_to_Keep).

This is my first horse, and it got me wondering about what exactly the benefits are to keeping a horse around?

I read [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/is-a-horse-actually-faster-than-running) that horses are indeed faster than walking, and can be ridden to avoid being overencumbered. But what other benefits are there to having a horse?

Will they help me fight enemies? If so, how do they compare to myself and/or my companion (in this case Lydia)? Can they be sold for gold? If their only use is faster travel, can the be stored anywhere to stop them from dying?

**What are the benefits of having a horse?**

Comment: I was going to VTC opinion based but *maybe* there is an objectiveness to this. I still lean towards it being an opinion as to their benefits. (Some may say it's faster than walking which is a benefit, I'd argue fast travel is more cost effective.)

Comment: There's a joke here somewhere about climbing mountains, someone will find it.

Comment: @BlueBarren [The linked answer already found it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL6PZ.jpg)

Comment: @n_palum I'm trying to avoid subjectivity by providing some potential criteria of what a "benefit" is at the end of the question, but understand that an element of subjectivity may be read into potential answers

Comment: "providing some potential criteria" - googling what a horse does in Skyrim or looking at the Horse wiki page quickly shows a lot of what a horse is used for.

Comment: It's a reliable way to fill my lesser soul gems.

Comment: For vanilla Skyrim there are no benefits that aren't already mentioned in the question and linked question.

Comment: FYI, on PC the mod Convenient Horses adds tons more use and customisation to horses, including being a pack horse for anything that you can't (or don't want to) carry.

Answer (score 3):

Your linked answer has almost all of the benefits, but it is missing one that I recently discovered.

If you dismount the horse while in deep water, and re-mount, your horse can run across the water at full speed.

It's great for crossing large bodies of water.  There is simply no other way to get this kind of speed.

Answer (score -1):

Because of the way Skyrim physics works, horses are able to climb mountains like they're nothing, which makes travelling much easier. However, other than that, they provide little benefit. You cannot sell them, your companion can't ride them, and they're not useful in battle either.

Comment: Oh and they suck in battle and can't be sold, and Lydia is to stupid to know how a horse even works nvm how to ride it.